# Nested relationship stops working after first result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Here is the query I currently have:

```
$messages = Message::select('messages.*')
    ->where('post_id', 1)
    ->where('parent_id', 0)
    ->with(['children' => function ($query)
    {
        $query->take(3);
    }])
    ->paginate(10);
```

And here is the `children` relationship in my `Message.php` class:

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

This is the output I'm trying to get:

```
- Message 1
    - Message 1.1
    - Message 1.2
    - Message 1.3
- Message 2
    - Message 2.1
    - Message 2.2
    - Message 2.3
- Message 3
    - Message 3.1
    - Message 3.2
    - Message 3.3
- etc
```

But instead, it's returning this:

```
- Message 1
    - Message 1.1
    - Message 1.2
    - Message 1.3
- Message 2
- Message 3
- etc
```

The query seems to only return the children for the first result, but no other result after.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix my query to get the results I need?

Comment: Take a look at this post - https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Comment: I plan on getting the children messages of children in the future and, as far as I can tell, that tutorial doesn't cover that situation.

Comment: It would be helpful if that information was in the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer the question "What am I doing wrong?", if you follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for Eloquent eager loading, you'll see that the query you built translates to this:

```
select * from messages

select * from children where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...) limit 3
```

(Notice that I made up the `children` table name, as I don't know what name you use.)

After retrieving the records, Eloquent will build its object, using exactly what you asked for: all the messages, and all their children - **limited to 3 rows**. This is why you only get the children for the first `Message`.

---

Now, if you want to stick with eager loading, you could simply get rid of the closure in the `with` method:

```
$messages = Message::select('messages.*')
    ->where('post_id', 1)
    ->where('parent_id', 0)
    ->with('children') /* the constraint is gone */
    ->paginate(10);
```

With this paginated result, you'll have access to **all** the `Messages` and **all** their respective children. Next, e.g. in the controller, you can modify your result by filtering it or manually limiting each children group to 3. Or, you do it quick and dirty and use a loop with a `break` directly in your view.

But don't do it quick and dirty.

Comment: If a message had 10,000 children, wouldn't this solution retrieve ALL 10,000 children? And then I'd have to filter out 9,997 just to get 3?

Comment: Sure, you'd get all the children, but so does the constrained `with` you're using - you still retrieve *all* the children, it's just you limit them *after* you got them. By "you" I really mean "MySQL".

Comment: Which would be a massive hit to performance if that were the case. It doesn't make sense for me to retrieve 10,000 children if I filter it down to 3.

Comment: I agree. The solution I gave is a basic blueprint. Whether it works for you, you decide. Hopefully, you'll figure it out.